# How do I read tsv files with Jackson csv mapper?

Tags: csv, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

I'm using the Jackson CSV lib to read CSV files.

We've got the streaming example [from the documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv/wiki/CsvSchema) :

```
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
mapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.WRAP_AS_ARRAY);
ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(String[].class);
MappingIterator<String[]> values = reader.readValues("/path/to/file")
```

This works fine for CSV files.  However I can't see how I can configure it to use tab instead of comma as the field delimiter, in order to read TSV files.  The only config I can find for a column separator [relates to the CsvSchema class](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-csv/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/csv/CsvSchema.Builder.html), but there is no schema, since we don't know how many columns are in the file.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
CsvSchema  schema = mapper.schemaFor(String[].class).withColumnSeparator('\t');
ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(String[].class).with(schema);
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Your code returns a CsvSchema object - but I need to use the mapper in order to read the file, and after this line of code, the mapper is still configured to look for commas.

Comment: @mdarwin if the solution doesn't work then please don't accept the answer as correct. This creates a bad experience for users in the future.